# Keeping of flushing the memory state of a LSTM inside a batch

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to code a LSTM network that predicts the next vector of size `n_class`. I have a dataset of sequences of very different lengths. To avoid a lot of zero-padding, I would like to chunk my sequences into smaller bits of length `n_chunk`, and zero-pad only the very last chunk of each sequence (if necessary).

To still be able to train on the whole sequences, I would like to pass the memory state at the end of each chunk to initialise the memory state for the next chunk.

I would like to be able to train my network on batches of chunks. For instance, batches of `n_batch` chunks of `n_chunk` frames each (ie a tensor of shape `[n_batch,n_chunk,n_class]`), that might belong to different sequences, but that are not shuffled (ie, each chunk in the batch is either a new sequence, or the continuation of the previous chunk).

From what I have understood, I can set the state before processing each batch with the `initial_state` argument of `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`. But it seems that this only sets the initial state before processing each batch. I don't know if the state is kept between sequences of each batch.

I have three questions :

1. When processing each batch, are all the sequences in the batch processed in parallel or sequentially ?
2. If they are processed sequentially, is the state reinitialised at the end of each sequence in the batch ? Or is the state at the end of each sequence in the batch kept by default for the next one, and only reinitialised at the end of the batch ?
3. How can I control when the memory should be flushed and when it should be kept ?

I have tried to answer those questions from Tensorflow documentation but I couldn't find the info I needed. Any help would be much appreciated ! Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your questions correctly: the state vector has a Batch dimension, so each of its elements will correspond to each respective element of the batch. One of the values returned by `dynamic_rnn` is the resultant state after processing all sequences in the current batch (the second returned value). Each time you call `sess.run` for each batch, you can also include that variable in the list of things that `sess` has to execute (so you get a numpy array back). From there, you have a choice of either feeding that resultant state back into the next call of `dynamic_rnn` or flush it and feed the fresh state again.

Something along the following lines:

```
# original definitions:
H_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, cell_size*layers])
Y, H = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, initial_state=H_in)

# then, when you run the session:
zero_state = np.zeros([batch_size, cell_size * layers])
feed_dict = {..., H_in: zero_state}
_, y, out_state = sess.run([training_op, Y, H], feed_dict=feed_dict)
#so now out_state == H
#so for next iteration, you can say:
zero_state = out_state
#or not, if you want to feed zeros again for the next batch
```

Also, in case you weren't aware, keep in mind that `dynamic_rnn` is designed to run sequences of varying length within the SAME batch, so this might help you to avoid some brain damage of slicing and dicing your sequences -- might work automatically!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !

Regarding the `dynamic_rnn`, I know that it is designed for sequences of varying lengths. The problem is that it takes a Numpy tensor as input, which means that all the sequences have to be zero-padded to be the same length anyway. In my case, I cannot load more than 1 sequence without getting an OOM error (because the longest sequence is really long), so I was considering alternatives to avoid that !

Comment: From you answer, you seem to say that all the sequences in the batch are processed in parallel, and that `out_state` contains the last state for each sequence.

Your answer would work for me if, for instance, my first batch contained the first `n_chunk` elements of my sequences, the second batch contained the next `n_chunk` elements, and so on until the end of all sequences. That way, I could pass the last state to the next batch as you suggest.

Comment: That is not exactly what I asked : I wanted that the final state of each sequence in the batch be passed to the next sequence of the same batch, but I am afraid this is not possible. If anyone knows that, it would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Really sorry for the multiple comments, I haven't found another way to reply on more than 600 caracters !

Comment: Have you tried supplying the 'sequence_length' parameter to dynamic_rnn to avoid the OOM error? The idea there is to pvovide a vector with each value containing the length for which you want each element of the batch to run. So if only one or your elements is really long, then I think it should know not to pad/run the other ones for that long? So if you provide something like [2000, 3,4,5], then it will only run the first sequence for 2000 iterations and the others for 3,4, and 5

Comment: regarding passing the state from one sequence to the next within the batch, I'd imagine that's sort of against the purpose, because the idea is to train the model simultaneously on several pieces of input? In other words, how can it process 1/5th of your batch and then give the state to the second 1/5th of the batch? Maybe in this case get rid of the batch approach and use the batch of 1? This would probably be slow but will let you pass the state carefully from one iteration to the next

Comment: From what I have read online (to be taken with a grain of salt), when the `sequence_length` parameter is used, the `dynamic_rnn` copies the last value for the rest of the sequence (the output too is a numpy array, all his elements have to be of same dimension). This saves a lot of computations, but that doesn't save memory, I would still have a lot of padded values.

Also, your explanation on the batches indeed makes sense, thank you very much for clarifying this !